# installing a python library that does not contain setup.py

Tags: python, module, installation

I am trying to install a python library, seeming it does not have a `setup.py` 
https://github.com/galeo/pyflit

Is there any way I could install it manually or without the `setup.py` (without creating my own `setup.py` because I'm still new in python)?

I have tried installing it using pip with a local directory but it only installs one `.py` file at a time which probably means I'm installing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy the whole `pyflit` directory into a directory listed on your Python path.

Usually the `lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory is fine, but you can take a look at `python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'` for ideas.

Comment: @PeterWood: Thanks! Corrected.

Comment: I had to check. I was thinking, these young-uns, getting into the good old tools

Comment: Well, I don't use it any more either. [Behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/) works well enough.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing solution! solved my problem!

Comment: You need to start and end the code with double-quotes `"import sys; print sys.path"`

Comment: @PeterWood: bash accepts both quote styles, provided I remember to include the closing quote :-P